# How to tokenize a word containing punctuation using NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I have a [`PlainTextCorpusReader`](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/plaintext.html), and the text is job ads scraped from the web. I want to strip out the skills using NLTK.

But I have failed at the first hurdle as the reader is tokenizing the word 'C#' as 'C','#'.

I do want to filter out the noise such as stopwords and punctuation, so this is a problem.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Well, how about basic string splitting in python?

Comment: How about an example of what you mean, in the context of a plaintextcorpusreader?

Comment: You haven't given a lot of information here so it's hard to figure out exactly what you want. But any string in python can have the .split() function called on it, you could also probably use regex's to solve this problem. Some example code would be helpful if you need an answer more specific then that however.

Comment: This is a duplicate, there are [70 questions on *NLTK tokenize punctuation*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NLTK+tokenize+punctuation+is%3Aquestion), please read them.

Comment: You could also just clean up your list after the tokenization. Really, without seeing much example data, its hard to say which approach is most fruitful and/or least time consuming

Comment: Of the 70 articles linked to, the only one that is relevant is this article here. So that for me is the canonical definition of unique, and the diametric opposite of duplicate.

Comment: All of the information required was supplied with the question. What information do you identify as missing? You have the library, the specific class, the specific method and a specific example of input and output, along with a definition of how the output differs from what is expected.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In this example, we need to see your current code, some examples of what is being parsed correctly and what is being parsed incorrectly, and an example of your desired results. Until then, I am flagging this post for removal.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is either to clean the string before using the corpus reader, using the replace method to replace 'C#' with something like 'CSharp' or to train the tokenizer.